# Django annotate(...) taking a dictionary

Tags: django, django-orm

I have somewhat complex django query with a lot of .annotate:

```
query = ModuleEngagement.objects.filter(course_id=course_id)\
            .values('username')\
            .annotate(
                videos_overall=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='video', then='count'), output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                videos_last_week=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='video', created__gt=seven_days_ago, then=1),
                                          output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                problems_overall=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='problem', then='count'), output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                problems_last_week=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='problem', created__gt=seven_days_ago, then='count'),
                                            output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                correct_problems_overall=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='problem', event='completed', then='count'),
                                                  output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                correct_problems_last_week=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='problem', event='completed',
                                                         created__gt=seven_days_ago, then='count'),
                                                    output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                problems_attempts_overall=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='problem', event='attempted', then='count'),
                                                   output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                problems_attempts_last_week=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='problem', event='attempted',
                                                          created__gt=seven_days_ago, then='count'),
                                                     output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                forum_posts_overall=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='discussion', then='count'),
                                             output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                forum_posts_last_week=Sum(Case(When(entity_type='discussion', created__gt=seven_days_ago, then='count'),
                                               output_field=IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(
                date_last_active=Max('created'))
```

Does annotate accept a dictionary as a parameter so I can move all the annotates into it? If so, what would be the syntax?

Comment: You can dictionary unpack them, so `**some_dict`. The dictionary contains the parameter names as string in the keys of the dictionary, and the corresponding expressions as values.

Comment: If you use Django-2.0, you can use `filter=...` in the `Sum(..)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am having some difficulty figuring the right syntax. I tried dict_parameters = { 'vo': 'videos_overall' =Sum(Case(When(entity_type='video', then='count'), output_field=IntegerField())), ...} but this appears to be incorrect syntax. Can you give an example of actual syntax?

Comment: the syntax is correct, but you need to *unpack* the dictionary, like `.annotate(**dict_parameters)`.

Comment: I am getting an error "can't assign to literal" - apparentyly 'videos_overall' can't be on the left hand of an assignment in the value of the dictionary. Am I missing a part of syntax?

Comment: your dictionary uses wrong syntax, it is `key : value`, not `key=value`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does annotate accept a dictionary as a parameter so I can move all the annotates into it? If so, what would be the syntax?

You can perform *dictionary unpacking*. So if you have a dictionary like:

```
my_dict = {
    'total_likes': Sum('likes'),
    'total_articles': Sum('articles'),
}
```

The you can have a query like:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(**my_dict)
```

This is then equivalent to:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(total_likes=Sum('likes'), total_articles=Sum('articles'))
```

If you use [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) or more recent, then you can significantly simplify your annotations with:

```
ModuleEngagement.objects.filter(course_id=course_id).values('username').annotate(
    videos_overall=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='video')),
    videos_last_week=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='video', created__gt=seven_days_ago)),
    problems_overall=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='problem'),
    problems_last_week=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='problem', created__gt=seven_days_ago)),
    correct_problems_overall=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='problem', event='completed'),
    correct_problems_last_week=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='problem', event='completed', created__gt=seven_days_ago)),
    problems_attempts_overall=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='problem', event='attempted'),
    problems_attempts_last_week=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='problem', event='attempted', created__gt=seven_days_ago)),
    forum_posts__overall=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='discussion'),
    forum_posts__last_week=Count('pk', filter=Q(entity_type='discussion', event='attempted', created__gt=seven_days_ago)),
    date_last_active=Max('created')
).order_by('username')
```